# Change what closing the lid does, from the commandline?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, power

I wonder if anybody knows a utility, or command, which can change this setting in windows in one click. I often need to change it on my laptop whether I want it to do nothing when the lid is closed or go to sleep.

I'm sure it's possible to change somehow from the command line.

Answer (score 25):

Taken from [Set On Lid Close Power Option](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/85107-set-on-lid-close-power-option/). There is also a script or two on this page, but the method reproduced below is the best, IMHO.

---

You can set it through `powercfg` commands.

The pre-configured schemes have the following GUIDs:

```
Power Scheme GUID: 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e  (Balanced)
Power Scheme GUID: 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c  (High performance)
Power Scheme GUID: a1841308-3541-4fab-bc81-f71556f20b4a  (Power saver)
```

I'll use the Balanced scheme for my examples, but you would use the GUID provided by:

```
powercfg -GETACTIVESCHEME
```

You can find the GUIDs for subgroups and power settings as well as the index values for each power setting by running a query command with your scheme GUID:

```
powercfg -Q 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e
```

Looking through the output, you will discover that the subgroup GUID you want is:

```
Subgroup GUID: 4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347  (Power buttons and lid)
```

and the power setting:

```
Power Setting GUID: 5ca83367-6e45-459f-a27b-476b1d01c936  (Lid close action)
```

with index options:

```
Possible Setting Index: 000
Possible Setting Friendly Name: Do nothing
Possible Setting Index: 001
Possible Setting Friendly Name: Sleep
Possible Setting Index: 002
Possible Setting Friendly Name: Hibernate
Possible Setting Index: 003
Possible Setting Friendly Name: Shut down
```

**So in order to configure your system to shut down when the lid is closed, you would run:**

```
powercfg -SETACVALUEINDEX 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e 4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347 5ca83367-6e45-459f-a27b-476b1d01c936 3
powercfg -SETDCVALUEINDEX 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e 4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347 5ca83367-6e45-459f-a27b-476b1d01c936 3
```

**Note**: These two lines are ***identical***, apart from:

- **`AC`** in `SETACVALUEINDEX` for the "*Plugged In*" action, and;
- **`DC`** in `SETDCVALUEINDEX` for the "*On Battery*" action.

---

#### Additional Note

From [this post](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/85107-set-on-lid-close-power-option/?do=findComment&comment=1173900):

Settings made via the command line *must* be followed with

```
powercfg -setactive <GUID>`
```

That is to say, for 'Balanced'

```
powercfg -setactive 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e
```

---

Please note that I have not block quoted, as it messed up the rather long code lines. So for the sake of formatting, I have left it unquoted.

Answer (score 14):

The following seems the easiest and also somewhat readable way to change the behavior from command line for the **currently active power scheme** (thanks to [w17t's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1259975/316320) and [this TenForums post](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/69762-change-lid-close-default-action-windows-10-a.html)):

##### *DoNothingWhenClosingTheLid.bat*

```csh
::Do nothing when you close the lid
powercfg /setACvalueIndex scheme_current sub_buttons lidAction 0
powercfg /setDCvalueIndex scheme_current sub_buttons lidAction 0

::Re-activate current scheme to make settings take effect immediately
powercfg /setActive scheme_current
```

##### *GoToSleepWhenClosingTheLid.bat*

```csh
::Go to sleep/standby mode when you close the lid
powercfg /setACvalueIndex scheme_current sub_buttons lidAction 1
powercfg /setDCvalueIndex scheme_current sub_buttons lidAction 1

::Re-activate current scheme to make settings take effect immediately
powercfg /setActive scheme_current
```

Comment: Underrated post!

Comment: Seemed I needed to restart the computer as well for the change to take effect.

Answer (score 5):

Here's another strategy using the WMI [**`Power Policy Provider`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/powerwmiprov/power-policy-provider-) classes and the [**`Cim Cmdlets`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/?view=powershell-7.2) modules

```bsh
$powerNamespace = @{ Namespace = 'root\cimv2\power' }

# https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/power-settings/power-button-and-lid-settings-lid-switch-close-action
enum LidAction {
    DoNothing = 0
    Sleep = 1
    Hibernate = 2
    ShutDown = 3
}

enum PowerSupply {
    AC # Plugged In
    DC # On Battery
}

# get active plan
$curPlan = Get-CimInstance @powerNamespace -Class Win32_PowerPlan -Filter "IsActive = TRUE"

# get lid closed setting
$lidSetting = Get-CimInstance @powerNamespace -ClassName Win32_Powersetting -Filter "ElementName = 'Lid close action'"

# get guids
$planGuid = [Regex]::Matches($curPlan.InstanceId, "{.*}" ).Value
$lidGuid = [Regex]::Matches($lidSetting.InstanceID, "{.*}" ).Value

# get plugged in lid setting    
$pluggedInLidSetting = Get-CimInstance @powerNamespace -ClassName Win32_PowerSettingDataIndex `
    -Filter "InstanceID = 'Microsoft:PowerSettingDataIndex\\$planGuid\\$([PowerSupply]::AC)\\$lidGuid'"

# set lid action to do nothing
$pluggedInLidSetting | Set-CimInstance -Property @{ SettingIndexValue = [int][LidAction]::DoNothing }

# refresh to activate
$curPlan | Invoke-CimMethod -MethodName Activate
```

#### Further Reading

- [PowerShell/WMI power management](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35325862/1366033)
- [Powershell Set Lid Close Action](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15455864/1366033)
- [Created a script to toggle lid close action](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23944639/1366033)

Comment: After changing a few Filter Values it worked. But two weird things happen. First the last command does not work: "This Method is not implemented in any class" (translated from german). Second The menu still shows the default value "shutdown" but after a reboot closing the lid "does nothing"

Answer (score 3):

`powercfg` supports aliases for guids (scheme names, groups etc)

```
@echo off

powercfg /s scheme_min
rem scheme_min is high performance

powercfg /setacvalueindex scheme_min sub_buttons lidaction 0
rem under buttons group; plugged in

powercfg /setdcvalueindex scheme_min sub_buttons lidaction 0

rem dc means on battery

rem check with powercfg.cpl gui

rem use powercfg /aliases for aliases instead of guid numbers

rem query with powercfg /q
```

this script above would switch to high performance scheme and set the lid action (`When I close the lid:`) under it to be `None` on both cases (either plugged or when on battery).

it is basically three lines of code as the rest are almost just comments (***rem***arks).