# How can I make my screen stay on after closing the laptop lid? Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, laptop, display

I'm trying to use my laptop (mostly to play videogames) through my phone while I'm away with Parsec, however if I close the lid the screen turns off which causes the framerate to drop to 1 and the PC also stops taking any inputs. I can't leave my laptop open while I'm away for various reasons.

I've tried:
`gpedit.msc` - `Select the lid switch action`
`Device Manager` - changing `ACPI lid` driver to `Volume Manager`

Googling the issue didn't yield many more results, as people usually want the screen to turn off.

Thanks!

Comment: Does the computer sleep when you close the lid (since you wrote `"the PC also stops taking any inputs"`) or did you disable that?

Answer (score 3):

I'm answering what seems to be the question from the question's body: "the PC also stops taking any inputs". This is how you prevent the computer **from sleeping** when the lid is closed: (if the question is about the screen itself - it looks like you've already seen the answers to my question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1097780/prevent-screen-turning-off-when-lid-is-closed). I can just add that at the time I asked that question, I ended up giving up on it :( .)

1. Right click on the battery icon in the system tray
2. Power Options
3. Choose what closing the lid does (on the left)
4. "When I close the lid:" (click on the appropriate dropdown)
5. "Do Nothing".
6. Click the "Save changes" button.

Comment: I believe this still shuts down the laptop screen but prevents the laptop from sleeping/powering off etc